# Automatic Clean-Up of Code in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, settings, code-cleanup

I am wondering, if it is possible, to have some kind of automatic code-clean-up in Visual Studio 2010.

Especially interesting would be:

- Auto-Indent
- Remove tailing empty lines
- Remove unused usings

at special cases, e. g. on save of the file.

I haven't found anything in the options, but maybe I was just kinda blinded... ...afaik in eclipse it was at least possible to intend on save. There should be something like that in Visual Studio?

**UPDATE:** Thanks for the fast replies, the thing is that I am ware of the keyboard-shortcuts (but nevertheless thanks for mentioning), but I am working through tons of foreign code by now and it would be awesom not having to do it manually for every file :)

Comment: A similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738441/is-there-any-way-to-mass-organise-usings-in-visual-studio-2012

Answer (score 8):

Auto-indent can be done with Edit/Advanced/Format Document, or equivalent keyboard shortcut (Ctrl-K, Ctrl-D for me, YMMV).

Tailing empty lines I'm not aware of an automatic solution for, though there may be an extension available (or you could write your own).

Removing unused `using`s is a built in VS refactoring, and also available in tools like Resharper or DevExpress.  (Right click code, then Organize Usings/Remove and sort.)

I'm not aware of a standard way to have these happen automatically for every document save, but you could probably write a macro or VS extension that would make this happen.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the above already exist directly in Visual Studio:

<kbd>Ctrl - K - D</kbd> will reformat the document (Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document).

There is a refactoring that deals with `using` statements (right click in the code, there is an option for "Organise Using").

As for empty lines, I don't know of anything built in.

But tools like Resharper do have code cleanup capabilities that deal with all of the above and more (Resharper menu -> Tools -> Cleanup Code).

None of the above will execute on save by default, but you should be able to write a [macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967.aspx) that runs on the save event.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [CodeMaid](http://www.codemaid.net/). Its an open source solution for what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

To Auto-indent you can ue ctrl+k+d pretty much like ctrl+shift+f in eclipse. But for unused usings I dont know any.