# Is there any way to mass organise usings in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, using

In Visual Studio 2010 I am aware you could use the PowerCommands extension to Right Click->Project and 'Remove and Sort Usings', I am also aware you can organise usings on a single file basis on the right click context menu.

I did find instructions to create a new macro which executed the organise usings command over your entire project to do this, however didn't get far with that - as I believe [macros are not supported in Visual Studio 2012](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/d8410838-085b-4647-8c42-e31b669c9f11/).

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this en-mass?

Comment: Please tell me how, I tried Right Click -> Clean Up Code, but everything to do with organising using statements doesn't actually remove unused or erroneous ones.

Comment: Ironically, I just found that out today. I thought that "Remove unused references" in R#7.0 would do it, but it leaves some behind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use [CodeMaid](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496) which seems to work fine doing this across the solution. Not too sure how it works under the covers though :)

Comment: Under the covers it simply invokes Visual Studio's built-in commands.